# How to record the screen in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5

hi am doing an app in iphone with camera integration.i am using an iphone 3gS for testing.
My client wants to see the app so he has asked me to send a video showing the complete workflow. Since the app uses camera i cant run the app on stimulator.
Is there any app for iphone which captures its screen.
i dont want to jailbreak my iphone

Comment: Why donot you create ipa and send to client to check app himself?

Comment: i was plannig to do that but the client insisted on giving a video

Comment: Then explain him that in simulator he will not be able to see camera functionality working. You can use [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) software for that to record screen..

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to natively record the screen on a non-jailbroken iPhone.

Two solutions occur to me:

1. Why not just use the simulator? It can't take photos, sure, but you can "rig" the code to pretend a photo was taken, when in fact you're using a dummy shot. Be sure to tell the client, and explain the workflow is the same.
2. You could use AirPlay mirroring. Turn on Airplay mirroring, which streams the entire iPhone screen, mirroring to a Mac server like http://www.airserverapp.com/. Then record the mirrored output. There is a little lag in this process, but it should work fine.

Comment: He can also send ipa to his client after enrolling to developer program. So he can test app on his device himself.

Comment: I know people who have used the latter AirPlay mirroring approach with Reflection: http://reflectionapp.com/ in order to capture accelerometer-based games. It sounds like that works well.

Comment: Is this answer still current? Thanks!

Comment: @Crashalot To the best of my knowledge, yes. There are many more options if you're willing to jailbreak, but the "Record Airplay" is probably still the best bet for a locked device.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 11 will finally allow screen recording.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the client **must** have a video, you could always record the actual device with a digital camera.  I know this answer sounds like I'm mocking you, but I'm not...it might be the only way to record video from a non-jailbroken device.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to  @Adam Wright's second point. A "cleaner" way than actually using a digital camera may be to use [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) to display your iOS device's screen on your Mac and then use one of the many free screen recording apps on Mac (e.g QuickTime Player) to record that section of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

iTool is very good tool to record screen, all the professional guy use this, it has also more options just like itunes. Here is the link to download

http://itool.en.softonic.com/mac

Answer (score 0):

Open QuickTime on your Mac and run the application on simulator. Select New Screen Recording from File option and select only selected area or full screen option to record a video. That's it!